# How can I firstly transpose a matrix and then fill the value for missing month with 0

Tags: r, matrix

I have a question about matrix structure manipulation in R, how can I firstly transpose a matrix and then fill the value for missing month with 0.
For example, I have the data for the fruit shop with amount of apple and orange sold every month like follows,  the number should be numeric.

```
fruit   Month   amount
apple   1   243
apple   7   66
apple   8   22
orange  2   89
orange  5   12
```

However, I would like to transpose Ma and and set the amount of apple and orange for missing month to 0, like the following, could you please help with that?

```
Month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
apple   243 0   0   0   0   0   66  22  0   0   0   0
orange  0   89  0   0   12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()` so it is as reproducible as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(Ma[-1,],stringsAsFactors = F); names(data) <- Ma[1,]
data <- data %>% mutate(Month = as.numeric(Month),amount = as.numeric(amount)) %>%
  complete(Month = 1:12,fill= list(amount = 0)) %>% 
  dcast(Month~fruit, value.var = 'amount',fill = 0) %>% select(Month, apple, orange) %>% t()
```

install libs firstly:

```
install.packages(c('tidyverse','rechape2'))
```

Comment: FYI there is `spread` in `tidyverse` so no need to load `reshape2` just to `dcast`